# Telnet trouble on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1

Tags: windows-7, command-line, telnet

I'm trying to connect to a Telnet server. After typing 'telnet [server] [port]', I get a blank command prompt screen. I can then type Telnet commands, but everything I type is invisible.

Replies sent by the server are also invisible.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem also occurring on different machines? Did you try a different tool like Putty?
Try using a packet sniffer like Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) when connecting, you will see the packet flow which might tell you more.

Comment: Try to type 'Display LOCALECHO on' in the telnet window and see if that makes the commands visible.